# My Samsung Note 8.0 GT-N5100 is stuck in a boot loop. I want to retrieve data ... is there any hope?

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop

I am about to press "wipe data/factory reset" on the recovery menu, but have found this place and you are my last best hope!

I hope to rescue data from S-note and other apps, plus loads of photos and videos (although these are mainly backed up on google+)

I am not an expert but can and will follow difficult instructions if you explain them slowly!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Louise! I've just fixed up the tags on your question to make a better fit. Please check with their tag-wikis for first aid: [boot-loop](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) would be the one to start with; if you've solved that part, the other part should be much easier (or even become obsolete, as your problem is gone then). If you still need it, the [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) should get you started. Please let us know your progress, and good luck to you!

Comment: I have read throughthe bootloop link but am still unsure what to do .. here are my option:

Comment: reboot system now ... this makes no difference. - apply update from ADB ... - apply update from external storage ... - wipe data/ factory reset ... - wipe cache partiltion ... apply update from cache.

Comment: so nothing that ressembles the commands suggested apart form thre factory reset, which I am avoiding for now ...

Comment: Louise, you're talking about the *[recovery menu](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info)* – while the boot-loop stuff talks about *[safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info)*. Please follow the latter link for more details, and combine that with the corresponding text from the [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info).

Comment: thks, Izzy - so I have tried many combos of power/vol up/vol down/home and still no safe mode. I get a Custom OS screen from power+vol down, with a warning (can cause critical probs) and choice: continue/cancel. I've cancelled each time. Otherwise, that and the recovery menu (described earlier) are all I get. It powers up to the id screen then twirling design and tune, then a pulsating blue-white SAMSUNG sign which remains til I turn it off. (At this point the back and menu panels each side of the home button lit up, it vibrated and the screen/quill pen appeared) Battery charge also shows.

Comment: Please check with the Samsung help pages: [How do I start my Samsung Galaxy Note® 8.0 in Safe mode?](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00055191/66649/SGH-I467ZWAATT)

Comment: yeah I did that already and have just tried again, I can't get past stage 2 as the lock screen display doesn't come up :(

Comment: OK, I'm out then. Hopefully someone having a Samsung Note can be of further assistance.

Comment: what would happen I wonder, if I select wipe cache partition?

Comment: really grateful for your input, Izzy!

Comment: Nothing that hurts – go ahead and try. As the term "cache" implies, this is redundant data. Might even solve your problem, in fact.

Comment: oh well. I tried. nothing changed.  so I plucked up courage and wiped data/ factory reset.

Comment: Nothing has changed. Looks like I have a broken device. And now I need to find the receipts and get it back to Tesco's where I bought it nearly a year ago. sigh. thanks for everything, everyone!

Comment: spoke too soon ... left it for a few mins and there's signs of life! so the rest worked ... :)

Comment: So wiping cache did it? Glad to read your issue is solved! Would you make it an answer (describing what you did so it solved), and accept this answer then? That would help others with a similar issue to find your solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, wiping the cache did nothing. I decided to go ahead and reset it to factory settings. sad but better than having a broken device I suppose. there seems to have been no other way out.

Comment: That was a rather quick decision. Of course a factory-reset solves it – but now all your data is lost, which could have been prevented. Nevertheless: as it solved your issue, you should make that an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried various suggestions to get past the bootloop but could not even get into safe mode. All I had to work with were the options on the recovery menu. Clearing the cache partition seemed to make no difference, so I eventually gave up and selected wipe data/factory reset.

This also seemed top have no effect. However, the device unexpectedly closed itself down and when I restarted it, there were signs of life and it booted up again for the first time for weeks!

I went through the start-up procedures carefully and selected "restore" for any google/ Samsung data and applications, even though it said I had not backed any up ... and it seems that all my data has not been lost after all! I already knew that my pics and vids were on google+ so was not too disappointed to find quite an empty gallery, but was delighted to find ALL my S-note docs were restored, and a number of my apps.

Some - quite a few - are missing - all my kindle ebooks for example, but I will see if these are transferrable, and there are apps I can find again if I need them.

I would recommend anyone with a Samsung device to have a Samsung account and enable "back-up" - also to save as much data as poss onto the micro sim card.

Thanks to Izzy and everyone for helping me through this traumatic afternoon!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, for pics and videos, I believe you should be able to plug it into a pc using a USB cable and move the folders you want to a backup directory. For App data it may be hit and miss, some you may be able to find, but some will not be recoverable. 
Here are links that may be helpful to finding S-note related files:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1423592

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1455282

Mind if I ask what caused the boot loop in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for this ... when I plugged it into a laptop using USB it did not register ... I thought that may be because it had not booted up and could not be recognised by the laptop.

Comment: I fear that it may have stopped booting because I had let the device's memory get too full ... is that likely? I have tried swapping in an empty micro-sd card in case it could find more memory there to get started but this is probably just highlighting my ignorance!

Comment: Was the device on when you plugged it into your computer? It should register if your in the recovery menu. Are you using stock recovery?

Comment: I have tried again, and made sure it was on and in Android System Recovery (which I reached by pressing on and vol up simultaneously) and this time on the desktop computer, and still it did not appear on My Computer. Not sure what stock recovery is ...

Comment: @LouiseOwen Excellent to hear you got it working again, sorry I was unable to help further. Backup is always the best choice when working with electronics. Nandroid (the "n" is intentional) back up is the official unofficial method for android users, as it creates an EXACT copy of your phone in its current state. (apps, app data, contacts, text messages, pics, literally everything.) The only downside is this requires setting up a custom recovery.